# Why @Transactional also work in aop @Before method?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, aop

I have ProductService class in my project for Product CRUD

```
@Transactional
public Product registerNewProduct(ProductPayload productPayload) {
 Product product = productPayload.getProduct();
 PriceHistory priceHistory = productPayload.getPriceHistory();
 if(priceHistory == null)
  throw new PriceInfoNotExistException("Price info is needed to register new product.");
```

And before executing method, I'm trying to insert API call log info to my database using AOP @Before.

```
@Before("execution(com.example.demo.entity.Product com.example.demo.service.ProductService.*(..))")
public void beforeBeginTransaction(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
//some code here
productChangeHistoryRepository.saveAndFlush(productChangeHistory);
}
```

I'm testing CREATE operation without providing price info so I can get PriceInfoNotExistException.
But If PriceInfoNotExistException thrown, this code below executed but no data inserted.

```
productChangeHistoryRepository.saveAndFlush(productChangeHistory);
```

I think it's because of @Transactional annotation on registerNewProduct() method Because If I remove this annotation and test again without price info, log data successfully saves to database.

Is there any way that I can save some data in AOP @Before method while keeping the @Transactional annotation on my `registerNewProduct()`?

Comment: I understand your question.
But why do you want save change history of a rollbacked transaction that involve no change in database.
Maybe only log is need for that and an error message for the user.

Comment: Maybe my entity name gives you confusion! I need to save all the api call history whether it was successful or not!

Comment: Ok but I don't think saving api call in database is a good choice, it's too expensive. Simple log file could be enougth, or NoSQL solution like log Mongodb or Elasticsearch...

Comment: I haven't thought of that way. That's actually a very great idea. For now, my option is limited to RDBMS and that's why I store api call histories this way. But next time I will def consider your suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Spring will create a proxy method (where the execution of your @Before aspect code will be at first place) with all annotations the initial method have.

Not sure if AOP is a good choice to test the method. Try to mock different ProductPayload objects (with or without priceHistory) and call your method on it.

Comment: Thanks! I solved this issue by using ```@AfterThrowing``` instead of ```@Before``` and change ```execution``` from ```com.example.demo.service.ProductService.*(..)```  to ```com.example.demo.service.ProductController.*(..)```. This way, Saving REST call execution is not affected by rollback happened in ProductService

Comment: Why `@AfterThrowing`? You never mentioned before, that you only want to log something if an error occurs. I rather thought that you want to log when no error occurs, which would correspond to `@AfterReturning`.

Comment: I also use```@AfterReturning``` as well for when no error occurs! I only mentioned ```@AfterThrowing``` because my issue was log data not being inserted when there's exception thrown!